# divide every value in one column by each value in another column (for every factor level) in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with values in columns A and B. 
There is another column 'frequency' with 6 levels: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o2oaettbkbzwf9/datadata.csv?dl=0

I have to take the first value from column A and divide it by every value in column B (BUT only when A and B values belong to the same factor 'frequency' level). 
I have to repeat the same with all values in column A. 
I should create a new data frame. It should have information about the 'frequency' level.
I have never done anything like that... If anyone knows a solution and some simple explanation I would much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `by` to slice dataframe into groups for each *frequency* level and then run an `expand.grid` operation to bind all possible combinations of A and B. Then take the division of the two. Use `cbind` to retrieve the current frequency. And `!is.na(...)` is to filter out the NAs.

```
df <- read.csv('/path/to/datadata.csv')

dfList <- by(df, df$frequency, function(i){      
  a_b_df <- cbind(frequency=max(as.character(i$frequency)),
                  expand.grid(A=i$A[!is.na(i$A)], B=i$B[!is.na(i$B)]))

  a_b_df$div <- a_b_df$A / a_b_df$B
  return(a_b_df)
})

# FIRST DF ELEMENT, 10K
head(dfList$`10K`)
#   frequency         A        B       div
# 1       10K 0.2649175 2.541833 0.1042230
# 2       10K 0.6181931 2.541833 0.2432076
# 3       10K 1.1950971 2.541833 0.4701714
# 4       10K 2.6086954 2.541833 1.0263048
# 5       10K 0.3557454 2.541833 0.1399562
# 6       10K 1.9483414 2.541833 0.7665104

# SECOND DF ELEMENT, 12.5K
head(dfList$`12.5K`)
#   frequency         A        B       div
# 1     12.5K 1.3723178 2.138316 0.6417750
# 2     12.5K 1.2204621 2.138316 0.5707585
# 3     12.5K 1.1798552 2.138316 0.5517684
# 4     12.5K 0.5880284 2.138316 0.2749960
# 5     12.5K 0.4865612 2.138316 0.2275441
# 6     12.5K 0.5011111 2.138316 0.2343485

# ROW BIND ALL DF ELEMENTS INTO ONE LARGE DF
big_df <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```